# Approximation of $L^\infty$ functions by $\mathcal{D}$ functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $Q=(0,T)\times\Omega$ with $\Omega$ a bounded domain. I read this:

> "the inequality holds for all $f \in \mathcal{D}(Q)$, and by approximation, it holds for all $f \in L^\infty(Q)$ since the constants only depends on the $L^\infty$ norm of $f$."

What approximation is this? I thought it was density, but no such density result holds.

**Edit** The inequality is
$$\int_Q (u_1-u_2)f \leq C_{f}\times C_{u_1,u_2}$$
where $C_f$ is the constant that depends only on the $L^\infty$ norm of $f$. Here $u_i$ are $L^\infty(Q)$ functions.

Comment: You haven't said what $D(Q)$ is... (I guess it is standard notation, but what does it mean?)

Comment: It's $C_c^\infty(Q)$.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot.

Comment: In that case I agree with you, it seems to be implying use of a density argument, but there is no such density result. I don't know if could be due to the particular form of the inequality?

Comment: One would need more information, but if "the inequality" is something point-wise like $|f(x)|\le c$ where $c$ only depends on $\|f\|_\infty$ it would perhaps be enough to approximate $f$ in a suitable neighborhood of $x$ by a test function.

Comment: @Frank please see edited post.

Comment: @Jochen please see edited post.

Comment: And what kind of functions are $u_1,u_2$, and what kind of set is $\Omega$? These details are required too?

Comment: @Frank sorry. Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain. $u_i$ are $L^\infty(Q)$ functions.

Comment: Since $Q$ is bounded the inequality $\int (u_1-u_2) \le C_f \times const$ for $f\in L^\infty$ is rather trivial with $c_f=\|f\|_\infty$ and $const=$ the volume of $Q$.

Comment: @Jochen Sorry, that constant depends on $u_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $f \in L^\infty$, you can find a sequence $f_n \in C_c^\infty$ such that $\|f_n\|_\infty \le \|f\|_\infty$, and $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$, that is, $\|f-f_n\|_1 \to 0$.

Comment: Didn't you want to write $f_n\to f$ in $L^\infty$? Can you explain how to conclude please?

Comment: First, it is impossible to get $f_n \to f$ in $L^\infty$, because $L^\infty$ is not separable.  That is the whole point of the original poster's difficulty.  Second, since $u_1$ and $u_2$ are in $L^\infty$, we can conclude that $\int_Q(u_1-u_2)f_n \to \int_Q(u_1-u_2) f$.  In effect, I only need to find a sequence $f_n$ that converges *weakly* to $f$.